# Overlapping Inline Annotations with Quill

Tags: quill

In my application, users can create margin-comments anywhere in the document body, and the comment-anchor ranges can overlap arbitrarily, like this:

```
This [abc]is a set of [xyz]overlapping[/xyz] comments[/abc]
```

I'm defining my comment-anchor blot like this:

```
let Inline = Quill.import('blots/inline');

class CommentAnchorBlot extends Inline  {
  static create(commentId) {
    let node = super.create();
    node.setAttribute("class", "comment-anchor comment-anchor-" + commentId);
    return node;
  }

  static formats(node) {
    var classNames = node.getAttribute('class').split(/\s+/);
    for (var i = 0, len = classNames.length; i < len; i++) {
      var className = classNames[i];
      if (className.indexOf("comment-anchor-") === 0) {
        return className.replace("comment-anchor-", "");
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
CommentAnchorBlot.blotName = 'comment';
CommentAnchorBlot.className = 'comment-anchor';
CommentAnchorBlot.tagName = 'span';
Quill.register(CommentAnchorBlot);
```

But when I test it out in a running Quill instance, it generates parchment like this:

```
{
  "ops" : [
    { "insert" : "This " },
    { "insert" : "is a set of ", "attributes" : { "comment" : "abc" } },
    { "insert" : "overlapping ", "attributes" : { "comment" : "xyz" } },
    { "insert" : " comments", "attributes" : { "comment" : "abc" } }
  ]
}
```

Which is problematic, because the word "overlapping" should actually have both "abc" and "xyz" as its comment anchor IDs.

How would you recommend changing the CommentAnchorBlot definition, to accommodate this requirement? I haven't seen any other examples in the Quill documentation that work quite like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I would use a class attributor instead, as it seems unnecessary that a comment get its own DOM node and instead could just be a class applied to other nodes.

Secondly and to your point, most of the time formatting is an overwriting behavior (formatting text color to red, and then blue, makes it blue, not [red, blue]) but you can change this with something like this:

```
class Comment extends Parchment.Attributor.Class {
  constructor(attrName = 'comment', keyName = 'comment') {
    super(attrName, keyName, { scope: Parchment.Scope.INLINE_ATTRIBUTE });
  }

  add(node, value) {
    if (!this.canAdd(node, value)) return false;
    const array = Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
    array.forEach((id) => {
      node.classList.add(`${this.keyName}-${id}`);
    });
    return true;
  }

  remove(node, id) {
    if (id == null) {
      super.remove(node);
    } else {
      node.classList.remove(`${this.keyName}-${id}`);
      if (node.classList.length === 0) {
        node.removeAttribute('class');
      }
    }
  }

  value(node) {
    const prefix = `${this.keyName}-`;
    const list = _.filter(node.classList, (c) => {
      return c.startsWith(prefix);
    }).map((c) => {
      return c.slice(prefix.length);
    });
    return (list.length > 0) ? list : null;
  }
}

Quill.register({ 'formats/comment': new Comment() });
```

Comment: Nice! This looks very promising... However, when I use this code, the comment ID class is added to the parent block (paragraph), rather than just wrapping the currently-selected text in a span, which I prefer... Does that make sense, or should I put together a code sample to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Actually I think I just typo'd the scope. It should be INLINE_ATTRIBUTE not INLINE_ATTRIBUTOR. Check if that works? I'll edit the code in the post.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm now... Thanks again for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I have a quick follow-up question... How do I remove one comment with this scheme? Right now, I'm calling `editor.formatText(index, size, { "comment" : false })`, but that removes *all* comments from the designated range, rather than just a specific comment...

Comment: I can't figure out how to actually call the `remove(node, id)` function to remove *just one* of the comment IDs. Can you clarify how this works?

Comment: If you want to go through the top level API like formatText then one way is to use a prefix like '-' to designate removal and handle the case in `add`. This is how formatText(0, 1, 'indent', '+1') works (code in formats/indent.js). Alternatively if you save the comment attributor before passing into `register` you can use `remove` directly. Quill's mutation observer should still detect the difference and correctly update and emit the text-change event.