# angular 5 and quilljs [Parchment] Unable to create blot

Tags: angular, typescript, quill

I'm working with [primeng editor](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor) and there is no any problem with editor itself, however I'm fighting two days in a row with extending standard block for custom tag, official documentation says for any additional feature to use [quilljs api](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/)

I've checked every api and issue on github and it seems to me, I'm on the right way, but I can't rid off this annoying error:

```
ERROR Error: [Parchment] Unable to create marker blot
at new ParchmentError (scripts.bundle.js:148)
at Object.create (scripts.bundle.js:178)
at BlockBlot.insertAt (scripts.bundle.js:7323)
at Block.insertAt (scripts.bundle.js:855)
at Scroll.ContainerBlot.insertAt (scripts.bundle.js:3404)
at ScrollBlot.insertAt (scripts.bundle.js:7060)
at Scroll.insertAt (scripts.bundle.js:4252)
at Editor.insertEmbed (scripts.bundle.js:2606)
at scripts.bundle.js:1379
at Quill.modify (scripts.bundle.js:1610)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to add custom tag with non editable content inside. Here is my code:

```
...
import {Editor} from 'primeng/editor';

import * as Quill from 'quill';
import * as Parchment from 'parchment';
const Block = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');
class BlockEmbed extends Parchment.default.Embed {}
BlockEmbed.prototype = Block.prototype;

export class Variable extends BlockEmbed {

  static blotName = 'marker';
  static tagName = 'marker';

  static create(value: any) {
    console.log(value);
    const node = (super.create(value) as any);
    node.innerHTML = '<span contenteditable=false>' + value + '</span>';
    node.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
    return node;
  }

}

Variable.blotName = 'marker';
Variable.tagName = 'marker';

Quill.register('formats/marker', Variable);

@Component({
  selector: 'manager',
  templateUrl: './manager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manager.component.css']
})

export class ManagerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

   private quill: any;
  @ViewChild(Editor) editorComponent: Editor;

  ngOnInit() {}

 // based on primeng github issue this how we can get references to quill 
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.quill = this.editorComponent.quill;
  }

 variableSelected(event) {
    // grubbing string variable from event 
    this.quill.insertEmbed(this.cursor.index || 0, 'marker', event.value);
  }

}
```

Based on these topics from quill github, my code should work fine:

[topic 1](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1236)

[topic 2](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/850)

[topic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204899/what-does-the-quill-js-formats-method-do)

[topic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359148/overlapping-inline-annotations-with-quill)

So could somebody help me to find what I'm missing or where my problem is? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was apple to fix my problem with next approach

```
...
declare var Quill: any;
const BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/embed');

export class Variable extends BlockEmbed {

  static create(value: any) {
    const node = super.create(typeof value === 'object' ? value.text : value);
    node.innerText = typeof value === 'object' ? value.text : value;
    node.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
    return node;
  }

  static value(node) {
    return {
      style: node.getAttribute('contenteditable'),
      text: node.innerText
    };
  }

}

Variable['blotName'] = 'marker';
Variable['className'] = 'marker';
Variable['tagName'] = 'span';

Quill.register('formats/marker', Variable);

export class ManagerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  private quill: any;

  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper;
  @ViewChild(Editor) editorComponent: Editor;

...

variableSelected(event) {
    this.quill.insertEmbed(this.cursor.index || 0, 'marker', event.value, 'user');
    this.quill.update('user'); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, it was really useful!

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me in that way:

```
import * as QuillNamespace from 'quill';
const Quill: any = QuillNamespace;

const BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick in my case. I'm using [ngx-quill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill) and trying with `declare var Quill: any;` would apparently put my custom blot on some import of Quill, but obviously not the one ngx-quill is using...

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue using ngx-quill. I believe the problem is related to the fact that the component is declared in a scope hidden by webpack. Therefore we do not have access to the right Quill instance to register the extra components. 
I got a solution thanks to the help of KillerCodeMonkey at https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill. Remove any other quill.js import (in package.json or .angular-cli.json) and this should work on angular/core 5.2.0:

```
import * as Quill from 'quill'; 
import Parchment from "parchment";

console.log(Quill);
const QuillBlockEmbed = (Quill as any).import('blots/block/embed');

class BlockEmbed extends Parchment.Embed {};
BlockEmbed.prototype = QuillBlockEmbed.prototype;

class MyBlot extends BlockEmbed {
    static create(value) {
        let node: Element = super.create(value) as Element;
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            node.classList.add("my-class");
        }
        return node;
    }
...
}

MyBlot.blotName = 'boltTwo';
MyBlot.tagName = 'img';

(Quill as any).register({ 'blots/myblot':MyBlot});
```

Comment: see my answer below, you need to declare quill as any, since Quill is defined globally from the JS file,  just let's typescript know that the variable is defined from outside of the scope of this file.

Comment: Actually if you simply declare quill as any, that variable is undefined and does not relate to the quill.js imported by ngx-quill through webpack. If you import quill.js through .angular-cli.json then the variable is defined but points to a different instance of quill.js than the one imported/used by the ngx-quill component.